# footable, expanded Row ID

Tags: row, footable

I am using footable in a project.
I try to retrieve the ID of an expanded row.
a.k.a I want to retrieve the attribute row ID whenever I expand a row.

I have tried several sugested solutions, but all I get is "undefined" as a result.

This did not work:

```
$('#CustOrderTab').bind('footable_row_expanded', function(e){
   var id = $(e.ft.row).val();
   console.log('Row: ' + id + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(id));
});
```

Neither did this:

```
$('#CustOrderTab').bind('footable_row_expanded', function(e){
   var id = $(e).attrib('id');
   console.log('Row: ' + id + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(id));
});
```

Neither did this:

```
$('#CustOrderTab').bind('footable_row_expanded', function(e){
   var id = $(e.ft.row).attrib('id');
   console.log('Row: ' + id + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(id));
});
```

Neither did this:

```
$('#CustOrderTab').bind('footable_row_expanded', function(e){
   var id = $(e).attrib('id');
   console.log('Row: ' + id + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(id));
});
```

Neither did this:

```
$('#CustOrderTab').bind('footable_row_expanded', function(e){
   var id = $(this).attrib('id');
   console.log('Row: ' + id + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(id));
});

#CustOrderTab is the table name.
```

Any ideas or suggestions is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up working around the footable and go for pure jquery.

```
$('#CustOrderTab').find('tr').click( function(){
  console.log('Row click: ' + ($(this).index()+1));
});
```

In the end it's all I needed.